# Customizing Acumatica B2B Shopping cart

Tags: acumatica

We are customizing the B2B Portal Ordering system with shopping cart look and feel, we ran into issue where we can't see the business logic in the Customization Manager, it's missing the code files. Could you pls confirm if we can customize B2B portal and also the code for calling Add To Cart functionality

Regards,
R.Muralidharan

Answer (score 4):

The source code browser only lists code from PX.Objects.dll; the portal code is included in SP.Objects.dll. I would recommend that you use a tool such as Reflector or ILSpy to disassemble the code - it is not obfuscated and should give you something which is really close to the original source code.